# Where are the servers?

Tags: league-of-legends

Is there a list of where the cities/states instead of the general location for League of Legends servers are located? Specifically, I'm looking for one on the east coast of the US. Since, even though I'm in NY, I still get 100-200 ping.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The US servers are located in Los Angeles - [source](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=282554#282554)
I have yet to find any location for the EU servers, they are a secret - [source](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=10688755#10688755)

Comment: thats a really old post. sure it hasnt changed?

Comment: They are in Los Angeles county, but not the actual city :D

Comment: @calccrypto could be, I am trying to find more info

Answer (score 10):

Like Blem stated the us servers are located in Los Angeles

The EU-west servers are located in Frankfurt, Germany ([Source](http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=2380633#post2380633))